# Async concurrency prevention class

Tags: c#, thread-safety, concurrency, async-await, task-parallel-library

Because I'm quite naive regarding C#'s Task Asynchronous Programming and concurrency in general, and because it's so difficult to test, I'm concerned about the safety of this code. It's likely that those topics, or something even more esoteric to me (e.g. processor-specific issues like volatility rules), caused me to overlook something obvious to you. Please help me understand what I missed here!

**Intent**

Given a `Func<T>` that does not support concurrency, we can safely initate the function concurrently, and receive `Task<T>`. Concurrent initiations are "joined" to one of two iterations of the function; the active iteration, or the single pending iteration. The caller may disallow joining an ongoing iteration, to avoid inconsistent outcomes.

**Contract**

- This `ExclusiveFunc` class requires a `Func<T>`, which is set at construction and cannot be changed.
- `ExclusiveFunc` has one public instance method, `Task<T> Run(bool joinLate = false)`, used to initiate, or "trigger", the `Func<T>`.
- `ExclusiveFunc` is safe for multi-threaded use. Multiple instances of `Func<T>` will never run concurrently from any concurrent calls to `Run`. When proxied through `ExclusiveFunc.Run`, the `Func<T>` is protected from self-concurrency issues that might be caused by scheduled tasks or other concurrent use.
- There will also never be more than one *pending* `Func<T>`. That is, there will at most be one `Func<T>` running, and one waiting to run. The `Func<T>` must be implemented such that the side-effects and return value of any single future iteration is sufficient for all pending callers.
- Callers receive `Task<T>` for the iteration they have joined, whether joining the running or the pending operation. `T` must be safe for concurrent use if concurrent callers will use the result.
- Because "joining a run late" may result in unacceptable dirty / stale information or missed processing, the default operation when `Func<T>` is already running is to instead set *one* iteration of `Func<T>` to run when the active operation is complete. In this default operation, the caller is guaranteed that `Func<T>` will begin some time *after* the request was made.
- Optionally, the caller may `joinLate` if knowledge of an ongoing iteration (including its return value and side effects) is sufficient, and initiating an additional iteration is not required.
- `ExclusiveFunc.Run` need not be awaited, if a "fire and forget" implementation is required. However, this implementation is not ideal for heavy usage as such, since every call to `Run` will internally `await` for the result on its own thread.
- All callers joined on any iteration of `Func<T>` will receive exceptions thrown by the specific iteration they await.
- Awaiting callers will not wait unnecessarily (such as for subsequent runs), and specifically a queued request will not be forced onto the thread that was running `Func<T>` at the moment it was queued, but instead will run on the thread  that queued it.
- The `ExclusiveFunc` class is not vulnerable to internal transition race conditions. It will not halt if `Func<T>` throws or the queue runs dry.

**Specific Concerns**

- Are there cross-platform issues caused by the `lock`-less implementation? For example, should `queue` be marked `volatile`?
- Are there exception-handling problems? For example, the caller does not receive exceptions, or exceptions crash the queue.
- Are there defects in where the work happens that cause unexpected results? For example, the a Task never completes because its thread also runs pending requests.
- Is the lack of Task methods options a problem? For example, does this cause incorrect SynchronizationContext?
- Is this likely to cause a thread pool problem? For example, using twice as many threads as the caller expects?
- Is there a problem with using one Task to synchronize multiple threads in this way?

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ExclusiveFunc<T>
{
    public ExclusiveFunc(Func<T> func)
    {
        queue = new Queue(() => {
            try {
                return func();
            }
            finally {
                queue = queue.Next();
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<T> Run(bool joinLate = false)
    {
        var a = queue;
        if (a.Current.Acquire())
        {
            a.Current.Acquired.Start();
            return await a.Current.Acquired;
        }
        if (joinLate) {
            return await a.Current.Acquired;
        }
        if (a.Pending.Acquire()) {
            await a.Current.Acquired;
            a.Pending.Acquired.Start();
        }
        return await a.Pending.Acquired;
    }

    private Queue queue;

    private class Queue
    {
        public readonly State Current;
        public readonly State Pending;
        public Queue(Func<T> func) : this(func, new State(func)) { }
        public Queue Next()
        {
            return new Queue(func, Pending);
        }

        private readonly Func<T> func;
        private Queue(Func<T> func, State pending)
        {
            this.func = func;
            Current = pending;
            Pending = new State(func);
        }
    }

    private class State
    {
        public Task<T> Acquired;
        public State(Func<T> func)
        {
            this.func = func;
        }
        public bool Acquire()
        {
            return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Acquired, new Task<T>(func), null) == null;
        }

        private readonly Func<T> func;
    }
}
```

**Tests**

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

public class ExclusiveIncrementer {
    private int locked = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    public int Slow() {
        Assert.Equal(0, Interlocked.Exchange(ref locked, 1));
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Assert.Equal(1, Interlocked.Exchange(ref locked, 0));
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    }
}

public class ExclusiveFuncTest_WithoutThreads {
    protected delegate Task<int> RunEf(bool joinLate = false);

    protected virtual RunEf GetRun() {
        return new ExclusiveFunc<int>(new ExclusiveIncrementer().Slow).Run;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ConcurrentRequestCanJoinOngoing() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var master = run();
        var slave = run(true);
        Assert.Equal(1, await master);
        Assert.Equal(1, await slave);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ConcurrentRequestCanQueueIfOngoing() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var immediate = run();
        var queued = run();
        Assert.Equal(1, await immediate);
        Assert.Equal(2, await queued);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ProceedsAfterQueueEmpty() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var first = run();
        Assert.Equal(1, await first);
        var second = run();
        Assert.Equal(2, await second);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task FireAndForgetCompletes() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var first = run();
        var second = run();
        Assert.Equal(2, await second);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task OrderDeterminedByCallNotAwait() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var first = run();
        var second = run();
        Assert.Equal(2, await second);
        Assert.Equal(1, await first);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task MultiplePendingShareOperation() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var blocking = run();
        var firstPending = run();
        var secondPending = run();
        Assert.Equal(2, await firstPending);
        Assert.Equal(2, await secondPending);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task JoinWillStartIfRequired() {
        var run = GetRun();
        var only = run(true);
        Assert.Equal(1, await only);
    }
}

public class ExclusiveFuncTest_WithThreads : ExclusiveFuncTest_WithoutThreads {
    protected override RunEf GetRun() {
        var run = base.GetRun();
        return runThread;

        Task<int> runThread(bool joinLate = false) {
            // We enforce order with Sleep, to allow human-readable test outcomes
            Thread.Sleep(30);
            return Task.Run(() => run(joinLate));
        }
    }
}
```

**Background** (not the main question, but ofc comments welcome):

I would like to separate the locking logic from several schedulable tasks in my system (e.g. scheduled conference call setups, due e-mails). While unlikely, very closely-scheduled tasks may run concurrently. Rather than artificially restricting the scheduling resolution to an arbitrary "almost certainly safe" value, I want to ensure there is at most one running. The caller may determine whether joining an ongoing run is sufficient or not.

I understand domain-specific idempotency/synchronization is typically preferable.

**Related:** (for Node.js)
[Concurrent fire and forget async task queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196971/concurrent-fire-and-forget-async-task-queue)

Comment: We don't expect deterministic test results, just a clear description and a trivial example which people can relate to.

Comment: @dfhwze I've add several tests for human consumption. The ones I'd posted earlier were really for my own use, intended to make it easier for me to test complex time-dependent sequencing. Please let me know if these are well-suited to this forum.

Comment: While most of the edits have been for clarification, be aware that in the future, it is advised to not make edits to the code after an answer is received, per [the Help center page _What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ah, I did not know. Note that the edit did not apply an other-person-discovered fix, and I did give the existing answerer an opportunity to correct that specific defect I discovered, indicated in the comments on his/her answer (which did not make significant revisions) below. Perhaps what the more appropriate response would have been, would be to revert that edit and answer the question myself?

Comment: mhmm... isn't this the same as if you run a task and chained the next one with `ContinueWith` and then used its task to chain the next one and so on...? Alternatively, wouldn't the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` be here easier to use?

Comment: @t3chb0t `ContinueWith` has a different threading and `SynchronizationContext` consequence than `await`; you can see more about that in this chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95070/discussion-between-dfhwze-and-shannon . If you think that difference is better, I'd love to understand why. Also, this implementation restricts the queue depth to 1, which makes ConcurrentQueue actually more difficult to implement.

Comment: Maybe another time as I'm not sure I entirely understand its purpose as the tests are pretty academic and I'm not able to come-up with any real-world scenario where this code might be useful. Can you help out with that and name some use-case where this is handy (other than in the _Background_ part - or reframe them)?

Comment: Thanks @t3chb0t; The background isn't really the main point of the question, and consequently the UnitTests are meant to illuminate the usage contract, rather than use cases. To address your concern, I added a "bigger picture" section named "Intent". Does that help? I can give a simple usage example, although it's not my situation: multiple visitors of a web site request the weather, which is proxied to an external service. Alternately, imagine two scheduled task end up running at the same time for any reason; but the task internals cause inconsistency if run concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

#### Foreword

I appreciate you taking the effort to edit your question time and again to clarify your goal. At first, I thought you were making a *synchronous task scheduler* using whatever thread is available at any given time, which would have been really cool as well! In fact, your smartly designed API could be augmented to become one if you allow:

- chaining pending executions
- a specific `Func<T>` instance for each `Run`

#### Review

I haven't found any scheduling-related or other major issues. I only have a couple of small remarks.

Designing private classes allows you to have more leverage in defining access modifiers and validating arguments of internal state and methods. However, I would include some sort of debug-only checks on validating arguments to detect bad design early in unit tests.

```
private class State
{
     public Task<T> Acquired; // <- OK, since your API does not allow public access to it
     public State(Func<T> func)
     {
          Debug.Assert(func != null); // or use Contracts API in Debug Mode
          this.func = func;
     }
}
```

A public API should use argument checks.

```
public ExclusiveFunc(Func<T> func)
{
    func = func ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func)); // <- a MUST in public API
    queue = new Queue(() => {
        try {
            return func();
        }
        finally {
            queue = queue.Next();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My pleasure and thanks for requesting clarification; it has yielded documentation that will help consumers if we keep this functionality in our library. Regarding `func != null`, you are right, that was lazy of me. C# 8.0 where are you ;)

Comment: I'm thinking further about your chaining variable `Func<T>` comments. I'd given it some consideration. One concern I ran into early was defeating garbage collection on a deep graph. Another was complexity when limiting depth on the obvious `ConcurrentQueue`. I definitely see the value (e.g. read and write operations might be components of a longer process that can be interleaved, but not concurrent).

Comment: FYI, found a place where exceptions will crash the scheduler, lmk if you want to search for it yourself as a puzzle before I edit.

Comment: It can throw on the line before `a.Pending.Acquired.Start();`, causing the queue to block. I'll add a catch block in a moment after you've had a chance to look.

Comment: @shannon you await a Task not started because current is already pending?

Comment: Close. Each Task is owned (or `Acquired`) by the first thread to join it. That thread is responsible for running it, and is also has exclusive rights to advance the `queue`. However, in the case of `Pending` it has to first `await` the `Running` Task, before calling `Task.Start` and entering `Func<T>`. If the `Pending` task throws while awaiting the `Running` task (before calling `Task.Start`), the `Pending` `Task<T>` will not start (or finish), and the `queue` will also not advance.

Comment: so you not only need a try finally with the func, but also with the start pending after await current

Comment: Right, the `Pending` requires a `try ... catch {}` (rather than `finally`). It should not rethrow the exception.

Comment: then how should you handle the exception? each thread awaiting handles the exception itself and the API just silently catches it? Perhaps a ContinueWith is more appropriate then in this case

Comment: Right, the exceptions are returned with every completed `Task<T>`. The scheduler should just swallow it (or possibly log them, but ultimately that is probably the caller's job), because it is conceptually a copy of the exception, only relevant for completion notice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95070/discussion-between-dfhwze-and-shannon).

Answer (score 0):

A few fixes / possible improvements:

---

**Scheduler Crash on Exception**

This is the most significant I've found. The thread responsible for Starting the Pending Task first awaits the Current Task completion, but an exception will abort this continuation, leaving the queue in a hung state. The exception should be caught.

```
if (a.Pending.Acquire()) {
    try {
        await a.Current.Acquired;
    }
    catch {}
    a.Pending.Acquired.Start();
}
```

(After discovering this defect, I first incorrectly edited the code, which a moderator pointed out to me. I've reverted the fix and moved it to this answer.)

---

**Contract-stated thread assignment mismatch**

**Disagreement between Pending and Current SynchronizationContext**